# How to Place a Image at the center of Screen using Canvas

Tags: android, image, canvas

I am using the canvas to display an image in Android. I want this image to occupy the center of the screen irrespective of the sizes of the screen. So how could i achieve it.

This is the snippet that i tried with, Please let me know your  ideas too.

```
@Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ..........
            ..........
            sampleImage.draw(canvas,getWidth(),getHeight()); // This moves the image to right end of the view.
            ..........
            ..........
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sampleImage.draw(
      canvas,
      getWidth()/2 - imageWidth/2,
      getHeight()/2 - imageHeight/2
);
```

;)

Comment: I also think that you should overload the OnSizeChanged of your view and then save the width and height of the view.

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thanks for your response, i tried with the following way, but still i didn't get the solution right. movie.draw(canvas,getWidth()/2 - BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.loader).getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2 - BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.loader).getHeight()/2);

Comment: Still it goes some where to the right side. not exactly at the center of my view. Please help if you have any ideas. Thanks...

Comment: Try to get the size from the actial bitmap that you will be drawing not from resources (decode it once). It will work much faster. What is 'movie' ?

Comment: Thanks lukas, i will try that, and let know the status.